# Is the increase in microcephaly in brazil caused by the zika virus?

Tags: virus

I heard a pod cast saying that the increase in microcephaly in brazil may not be caused by this zika virus and possibly other causes. How good is the connection between microcephaly and zika and could other factors be at play for the microcephaly

> It's the virus that's sparked concern around the globe and been
>   labelled 'a public health emergency' by the the World Health
>   Organisation.
>
> But now there are fresh questions about the suspected link between the
>   Zika virus and microcephaly which causes small heads in babies.

Link to discussion talking about some of the gaps

http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/breakfast/the-health-report:-zika-virus/7147524

Comment: Question 6 of [link](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31635/is-the-zika-virus-a-serious-threat) is a very similar questions to this. The question [about pyriproxyfen](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/does-pyriproxyfen-cause-microcephaly) floats around a possible answer to the possible scenario but does not answer the question.